# Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?

Tags: discussion, faq, scope

[Application stores,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/App_Store) online marketplaces where developers can submit their applications for purchase and/or download by end-users, are fast becoming the main avenue through which non-web developers distribute their software.

Almost every major operating system across every platform (i.e., desktop, tablet, phone) is now associated with its own application store

- [iOS](http://www.apple.com/iphone-5s/app-store/)
- [OS X](http://www.apple.com/osx/apps/app-store.html)
- [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps)
- [Windows 8](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/apps#Cat=t1)
- Application stores for phone operating systems, browsers, etc

These marketplaces often put very strict requirements on software being submitted, requiring rigorous and hard-to-navigate submission processes.  These are of chief concern to developers, as they must know how to develop for submission and fix errors that result in rejections.

More developers every day are using these marketplaces as a "tool" not only to host and deliver their software to end users, but also to act as a broker for purchases of and within the application.

It can be argued, therefore, that questions about submitting software to application marketplaces (to quote the faq) are about *"software tools commonly used by programmers"* and *"are unique to the programming profession"*.

Canonical link: `[Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)`

[Return to FAQ index](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow)

Comment: Stackoverflow says no, but for me it's a big YES for one reason:
I really have a hard time trying to understand the huge marketplaces requirements written from a legal point of view.
But when I come to Stackoverflow, I can read the requirements from the point of view of a developper. And I can understand the simple and practical answers.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

#### No.

Here's why: ultimately, these are customer support questions.  Only Apple can answer them in an authoritative way, because they make the rules; rules which, by their own admission, can change at any time without warning.  Consequently, any attempt by a non-employee to answer such questions inevitably leads to idly speculative answers like "I tried that once in my app, and it got accepted," relegating such questions to the moral equivalent of polls and highly-localized speculative opinions.

The only real reason that people direct these questions to anyone else but Apple is a consequence of the same effect that is felt at any large company like Apple or Facebook: either their customer support sucks, or people just assume that their customer support sucks. Even if it didn't, there is a vast mountain of questions that are asked by people that are not really qualified to ask them, questions which Apple probably feels they shouldn't have to answer.

And neither should we.

I'm philosophically opposed to any range of questions that acts as a proxy for some company's customer support, if for no other reason than the company should be handling the problem themselves. Taking the pressure off by providing an alternative outlet only removes the incentive for these companies to clean up their own messes, and involves outsiders who are not qualified to answer the questions properly anyway.

Comment: By the same token, every question in the `windows` tag on [su] is a support question that should be addressed to Microsoft. While I can see where you're coming from, and I tend to agree with your conclusion, your argument is invalid.

Comment: This question isn't about SuperUser.

Comment: So? Come to think of it, my argument applies to [tag:windows] on SO too. If you want to know how to code something in C#, ask MS!

Comment: No.  Our FAQ specifically allows that.  Coding questions are what we're all about, not customer service.  It's not about Apple either; if someone asks a question about how to get their app approved at the Windows Store, I'd close that as off-topic as well.

Comment: The "polling" sandtrap is an extremely important point; that's the most frequent result from questions that I've seen about Apple's App Store policy. Such answers also tend to devolve in comment threads: "I've done this" "Well, they say you can't" "Well, all eight hundred apps I have in the store use this" and so on.

Comment: I wanted to comment here and reinforce several aspects of this answer. We on the Ask Different site have been debating covering iTunes Connect (Apple Store) questions and we also do not want to be a proxy for customer support or for specific troubleshooting situations. Now, there are ways to ask a customer support/troubleshooting question to impart an expert's knowledge of the process and they have a place here, but that's ***despite the general rule that support/troubleshooting make poor Q&A topics*** and are saved by virtue of their utility to teach others how to solve problems they face.

Comment: *"The only real reason that people direct these questions to anyone else but Apple is a consequence of the same effect that is felt at any large company like Apple or Facebook..."* - as much as I criticize Apple, I've got to say their support is actually very good. You can call them a speak to a real person. The trick is you have to call them, and get out of "contact by email" mode. The same ***cannot*** be said about Google or Microsoft, though.

Comment: What should be the reason when voting to close such questions?

Comment: Yes, in a perfect world these would have been a customer support questions. Here on planet Earth many corporations offering "free" services do not consider themselves obliged to provide support.

Comment: @Demiurg: An unfortunate fact that is not our responsibility to fix.

Comment: I wasn't aware that the stackexchange community has official responsibilities.

Comment: @Demiurg: Exactly my point.

Comment: "...rules which, by their own admission, can change at any time without warning." Can't a programming language change without warning? Even when it doesn't, new features mean the best way of doing changes all the time. All this seems to mean is that we'd have to maintain an answer, much like every other piece of content on this site. I'm not sure why this matters.

Comment: The rest of your answer could also be applied to any piece of software and supporting information. The fact that many companies/foundations/standards bodies are crappy at documenting their work in a way that people can actually find info and supporting developers who have trouble is one of the primary reasons SO exists in the first place. What makes Apple's store any different on this front? Maybe there is some difference, but it's not articulated very well here (if at all).

Comment: @jpmc26: See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company

Comment: I posted a question here about Apple payments, and I got down voted. I had posted the same question to Apple regarding their payments, and they told me they couldn't address it until I submitted the app for review.

Comment: @user2233706: This is why we direct customer support questions to the companies that sell their own products.  Let them clean up their own messes.

Comment: The policy violation emails from the Google Play Store come from a no reply email address. So I cannot get help other than guessing. Guessing of a community is more fruitful than just me being a lonely wolf / hermit in a cave. Therefore in some cases it's ABSOLUTELY NOT off topic. It would be a huge mistake to just categorize all of this into "off topic". Unless SO wants to become irrelevant. I wish I could get help from straight from a company and that's what I usually aim for first. Then I come to SO.

Comment: @CsabaToth: Exercises like what you describe ("I have the same problem, any update?" "I tried this, but it didn't work," and all of the comments you see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjRqFbTHUOQ)) are the textbook definition of forum behavior, the very opposite of the kind of behavior we're trying to promote here.  Bad information is worse than no information, because it just wastes everyone's time.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Ok, I may misunderstand StackOverflow then. However I want to come to SO with software engineering questions and not to Quora or Reddit. But I understand that maybe that's not what is desired. I want to revoke my downvote but now it's locked.

Answer (score 42):

If we're talking technical questions such as

> How do I sign my application for the Apple Store?

then yes, this is on-topic, as much as

> How do I pack my application in a self-extracting executable?

But I guess this isn't the kind of question you have in mind.

To take examples from the [App Stores site proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702?phase=definition), I don't see questions like

> I created an app that only works with third-party hardware. Do I have to send the hardware to Apple to get approval? How do they test such apps?

and

> Is there a limit on how long you can hold on to an app name in <App market>?

fitting on Stack Overflow. These are not technical questions, they are social questions. In a professional setting, these questions may well be handled by someone from the marketing team or product management team rather than someone from the development team.

There is a whole social world around software, relating to how to manage software and IT projects (which have a way to go seriously haywire, more so than other industrial projects), how to sell it (is it a product? is it a service?), etc. There's a good argument for having separate questions and answers sites for these two audiences: Stack Overflow for programmers, and another site for concerns of programming businesses bridging technical and social audiences. I don't see these business concerns fitting on Stack Overflow.

Comment: This is as good a rationalization as any.  I answered the way I did because I wanted to highlight the real problems with such questions, and illustrate what a slippery slope they are.  The simple fact is that these questions are out of scope, for the same reasons that many other questions that only meet the metric of "concerns that pertain to programmers generally" are also out of scope.

Comment: Yes, I think this is the best argument: these are simply not _programming_ questions. They're questions about business, design, or marketing, with the occasional legal item thrown in. The fact that a developer with an SO account is handling these problems herself doesn't make them about programming. On the other hand, if a question can be formulated as a coding question, then it doesn't matter whether the cause of the problem is App Store Guidline Compliance. Not "Why did Apple reject my table view?", but "Apple said my table view is upside down, how do I flip it?
"

Answer (score 22):

If you are using the [iTunes Connect](http://www.apple.com/itunes/sellcontent/) service to sell your music, books, ads, applications, etc. and are struggling with how the service works, or don't get how Apple's publicly documented services work in real-life, [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour) would like the chance to host your questions and answers.

We of course generally close questions that fail to follow the norms of being objective (or good-subjective), well researched, properly documented, or reasonably scoped.

There are some areas where we don't want to field questions:

- Questions that cover pre-release, [NDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-disclosure_agreement)-only topics were and continue to be [off-topic for Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/faq).
- Code level questions are better suited to Stack Overflow and will generally be closed or evaluated for migration as appropriate.
- Things that are clearly op-ed pieces about how [awesome|sucky|ridiculous|shortsighted|wise|whatever] Apple's policies are. Those topics will be steered to the blog and chat rooms by closing posts solely about Apple's actions. This is no different than other questions on the site that ask how Apple works rather than asking how to use Apple products.

I can see how "code-level" might be confusing to some, so I'll elaborate on that line in hopes of clarifying our intent.

If you are an iOS or Mac developer and code signing (using [Xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode), scripts, or the `codesign` command line tool) is kicking your workflow to the curb - ask that detailed question on Stack Overflow.

If you are an iOS or Mac developer and wonder how code signing might affect your customers in different countries or a user wondering how to tell if an app is code signed (even if you are using the `codesign` tool from the command line), you might ask that on Ask Different since it's more of a user level / policy question than an implementation detail.

Comment: @Won't and "insert lawyer joke here"...

Comment: @Won't - I agree with the sentiment, but thankfully little about iTunes Connect and the various submission services is covered under NDA. The iTunes Connect Developer Guide is public information: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/1_Introduction/Introduction.html , for example. NDA typically comes in for prerelease stuff (new OS versions, etc.) and not as much for the App Store submission process or requirements.

Comment: Ah! This is great. I'm glad that there's a place for some good questions under this heading to fit in.

Answer (score 7):

Can I propose an alternative answer to Robert Harvey's well argued answer? Full disclaimer, I work for Google, not in a developer support role, but as one of the software engineers on Google Play, one of the given Application stores.

Firstly I would say questions don't only get asked because customer support sucks, or people assume it sucks. I would argue our customer support don't suck, we have some great people responding to questions, for free, through live-chat and email on the developer console website. I would agree that some developers either assume it sucks, or assume we will charge for support, because apparently some other application stores do.

But even if this wasn't true, I'd argue StackOverflow has a place for answering these questions. People ask questions on StackOverflow about Java assuming the javadoc sucks, or they haven't read it. And people answer them by pointing to the javadoc as a citation.

The argument a non-Googler can't answer questions authoritatively about Google Play is false, for the same reason someone who doesn't work for Oracle can answer a question about Java. They can point to the authoritative answers on `support.google.com` or `play.google.com` or `developer.android.com`. And like the answer to a Java question, that answer is then findable by anyone using Google or searching stackoverflow for search terms the original question used, but the support page might not.

So I agree, tech support questions like 'why was my app banned?" are definitely out of scope - they are a 1:1 tech support issue between the developer and the store. But questions like "How do you prevent new users from installing an app while supporting existing users" are a realistic question about the state of the app development (software development) world, and seem entirely in scope.

BTW, I don't have that much reputation on this account, but on my personal account I've been using SO since it was in beta, so I'm reasonably familiar with the site and issues.

Comment: This has always had some grey area to it, but the general policy it still holds true. People wanted to make this an exception to the [customer support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746/2370483) policy, but that invites all sorts of policy questions about the various app stores. Understand that the superior ethic here is MCVE, where the `V` stands for **verifiable**. If the question pertains to policy (which a great many do) or something else on the publisher's then we're left up a creek (i.e. we don't know why they won't accept your app)

Comment: If it is something that relates to policy then I'm fine with declaring it out of scope. But I think something where the V in verifiable holds should be in scope for stack overflow, and overzealous closers are using this question as a reason to shut down legitimate questions where developers can be helped. Which makes life worse for SO users.

Comment: Google customer support absolutely sucks @nick fortescue.
If you can tell me a reliable way to get in contact with Google support for issues like "why was my app banned?", then please post an answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67977185/how-to-get-in-contact-with-google-play-store-to-challenge-an-app-rejection  , and I shall stand corrected.

Answer (score -6):

There is no difference between an API called "app store" vs. any other API. I see no reason why questions like "how many EBS devices can you have on an AWS instance" should be fine while "(how) can you have private software distributions on the Apple app store" or "how long can you hold onto an app name" should be banned? Why? (that's a rhetorical question)

I have ZERO understanding for wasting any time whatsoever to limit what technical questions people can ask here and arguing about what should be closed down. I don't get it why people can't just answer what they know and move on when they don't know or don't care? Why wasting time about closing questions?

Totally beyond me. I'll never understand it and I don't want a meta argument about that either. I will simply take every opportunity to reject and refute and vote against any attempt to close down a question that someone is struggling with trying to design some IT solution.

Comment: The example question you use here as a strawman would *not* be fine, for the exact same reason.  It's subject to change at Amazon's discretion, and we're not Amazon.

Comment: But the question *is* *objectively* fine and lives a happy life here on stack exchange and is useful in practice. I knew I'd get a bunch of downvotes by the people for incessantly close and downvote everything. But I don't care. It needs to be said.

Comment: ...no, the policy is actually to shoot those kinds of questions down.  If you want to dislike it, then post a counter-question to this policy looking to discuss merits and demerits of why such questions should be permitted.  Be forewarned - you're gonna get a *lot* of us disagreeing with you, ironically with the same zeal that you have when it comes to why you think those kinds of questions should remain open.