# Should questions with app-store tag be used in audits contrary to policy?

Tags: support, review-audits

According to [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/608639), App Store questions are off-topic.

Assuming that questions tagged as [app-store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/app-store) are properly tagged, it might not be the best strategy to use questions tagged as [app-store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/app-store) for audit questions in some cases.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/5860928.

Comment: And I did not like casting a close vote on the question during the review. I even went back to Robert's answer to see if I could find a reason to leave it open.

Comment: That one's close to the borderline, but I think -- given that it requires configuration of the _build_ of the app -- that it's in fact dealing with the bare metal of dev work, and not off-topic. The app store questions that are problematic are the ones that either invite speculation about policy, or are really software support questions. There are also occasionally questions that pop up that are really _business_ concerns, but they're in the guise of "programming" questions mostly because one person (the coder) is doing _everything_.

Comment: @Josh - yeah, this is frustrating (me not being able to classify well enough). Have you seen the [Network Engineering Stack Exchange](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help) Help? It offers examples of on-topic and off-topic for subject matter to help draw a line. I kinda wish Stack Overflow did similar (especially with server configuration questions).

Comment: I think moderators can edit that help page. You could open a Meta.SO question soliciting examples. Seems like it would make a nice resource. [Pekka proposed something like that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179268/) a while ago; not sure if that was before or after NE.SE started.