# Are questions about iTunes Connect on topic on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, scope

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26764763/1864610) was asked today, regarding some aspect of Apple's site that had 'disappeared'. Apple's policy on what it does or does not make available is clearly off-topic, but the OP decided that Stack Overflow was the best place and reasoned that it falls under the heading of 'tools used by programmers'. That's a debate one could have on a per-case basis, but in this case it seems this was a transient state on the Apple site.

I have seen [Robert Harvey's piece](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company) about whether or not some customer support questions are on topic. iTunesConnect seems to fall into a grey area.

Is there some definitive guidance somewhere on how these questions should be handled.

For this question specifically, how best to go about deleting it, given the cause of the question was temporary and appears now to have been resolved?

Comment: You should be fair and leave a comment for the OP about the discussion here at the question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Good point. Done.

Comment: As the person who asked the question I was unsure if it was better suited for apple.stackexchange.com or stackoverflow. The process of creating an iOS app, provisioning and distributing it to testers is definitely related to programming. apple.stackexchange seems to be more for users not programmers.
It would be nice to have some clarity on where questions about the app testing and publishing process should be asked.

Comment: _"Have they removed the external testers feature for now? How can I access this feature now?"_ How are we supposed to know? Yeah, this might be primarily used by programmers, but this particular question can only really be answered by Apple, not other users of the app. We don't know if they removed it for now, or if there was a system glitch, or what happened. We just know it can't be seen. In other words, my view is you called it right.

Comment: @Kendra, the question was phrased that way because I assumed it was related to the scheduled maintenance. The answer could have easily been that it was not available in certain stages of submission or that some extra steps were needed to make it available. - All things other users would have been able to help with. Nevermind the specifics though, lets focus on "Are questions about iTunesConnect off topic?"

Comment: I was in the same boat as the author, since the whole process requires a lot of reviewing if you ticked off certain knobs and switches. For about an hour, i thought *I* had done something wrong in my latest build. There was no mention ANYWHERE about apple taking down external users for maintenance or whatever. One second it was there, then I uploaded a new build, then it was gone. So it very much seemed like it was something I did. And i believe everyone who encountered this thought the same thing.

Comment: What's the view on questions which ask "App rejected for reason X what can I do?"

Comment: @Anorak I've seen a few of those. Apple's messages tend to be very clear so I vote to close as 'Unclear what you're asking...'

Answer (score 22):

The general topic of whether questions about app stores are on topic on Stack Overflow is discussed in detail within [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic), but I'll present my thoughts on iTunes Connect specifically.

Questions about developer tools are on topic on Stack Overflow. We have no problem with Xcode questions of various types, for example. However, customer support issues and business-related matters are not on topic here. iTunes Connect straddles both of these areas, so it presents problems sometimes.

For example, I'd argue that a question about the application submission process from Xcode to iTunes Connect would be an on topic developer tools question. A question asking why iTunes Connect is down today would not be on topic. Neither would a question about how to access sales reports or set pricing for your application in the iTunes Connect web interface.

There's a gradient between those two ends, and to date I've given iTunes Connect questions the benefit of the doubt if they somehow involve a developer tool or development-related issue. We're not a support site for every time iTunes Connect goes down or changes its interface, but I have no problem with questions about Xcode's interaction with iTunes Connect or deployment questions involving codesigning being on Stack Overflow.

Comment: You should add something similar to the referenced question, then turn it into a faq, convert it to a wiki, cleanup, etc...

Answer (score 7):

There are definitely aspects of iTunes connect that are off topic here. "Agreements, Tax, and Banking", "Payments and Financial Reports".

However questions relating to app submission, approval and testing would often be on topic. iTunes Connect is definitely a tool used by programmers in this instance.

I suggest this simple distinction. I hope it's not too simple though.

> Questions relating to the "My Apps" section are ok, other sections are off topic.

Comment: I think that distinction is likely a little too simple. I'm sure there are plenty of questions that could be asked about the "My Apps" section that has nothing to do with programming. Good starting point, though. Brad's answer does give pretty good guidelines for the situation.

Answer (score 5):

I feel that this might be a better fit at "Ask Different" (apple.stackexchange.com) and if you take a look there you will find other iTunes Connect questions.

Even though the question has some relation to programming, this sounds closer to "is jenkins-ci.org down?" than to "How do I troubleshoot this problem with jenkins on my linux server"
I believe everyone would say the first is off-topic.