# Are questions regarding Apple's terms for app publishers valid on Stack Overflow, or any Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, scope, site-recommendation

I need clarification on an Apple policy and I'd like to ask the community for perspective.  I don't think this is on topic on Stack Overflow, but I think it might be within the Stack Exchange network.  Is this appropriate anywhere?

Comment: [tag:appstore-approval] doesn't mention any alternatives - maybe Ask Different (see e.g. http://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bios-appstore%5D+approval)?

Comment: bmike, a moderator on Ask Different, lists some of the App Store question types that they decided to accept over there: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272168/19679 . While I think tool-related questions about submitting to iTunes Connect or packaging for release in Xcode [are perfectly on-topic on Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276152/19679), questions about Apple approval of something can be a grey area. Ultimately, many of those can only be answered by Apple and might be best addressed to their dev forums.

Comment: To clarify, I have worked on iOS applications in the past, but I've never started my own project for personal publication.  Since I don't, yet have an Apple Dev account I thought I would ask for advice before I've written a single line of code.  There is no point in making an application, if it can't be used. :(

Comment: That last sentence of Brad Larson's comment is really the main point. Even if they were on-topic somewhere on the SE network, there's no guarantee anybody would be able to definitively answer your specific question unless they happened to work for Apple. Seems like you're better off just going to Apple directly to ask.

Comment: And here for the related technical questions which would be on-topic: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: @RLH - If your question about something being acceptable involves a technical topic, like "does this framework use private API that will cause rejection" or "what is the proper way to access a unique identifier within an application", you might be able to get an answer here. If your question is one of policy, like "will an application involving political satire be accepted", that's not something we'd be able to answer objectively.

Comment: Brad... it's close.  I'd like to create an internal currency, much like "Mobage tokens", which are used by Mobage games. Except, in my case, I want to give developers the ability to integrate into my currency storehouse.  It's more involved than that, but I'm not sure if that is within the realm of the Apple Developer/App ToS.

Comment: @RLH - If it's a question of whether Apple would accept that kind of a monetary system, that's most likely something we can't answer. You can try posing it in the Apple dev forums, but even then all people could do would be to point to prior cases of this either being accepted or not. It sounds like it's more of a business concern than a technical one.