# Correct workflow for migrating a deleted question

Tags: discussion, scope, deleted-questions, migration

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27972841/testflight-external-testers-upgrade-workflow-after-app-is-released-to-app-store) on SO that was closed because it had a downvote and no answers after 30 days. After looking through SO meta posts, it looks like a better home for this may be the [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) site where iTunes Connect questions are apparently [encouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272168/126352).

First, do you agree that Ask Different is a better home for this? Or does the question belong on SO and I just asked it wrong?

If it does belong on Ask Different, what's the right way to get it migrated?  Should I undelete it and then close it with the off-topic reason-- although Ask Different isn't one of the "other sites" available in the off-topic site list? Or flag for moderation as-is?  Or something else?

Comment: If your question was deleted with no answers, then just repost it yourself. There's no need to involve moderators or any other members of the community in an action you can take yourself.

Comment: OK, will do. Was not sure if it was bad etiquette to re-post a deleted question.

Comment: BTW, do you want to make your comment into an answer so I can accept it and *this* question won't get deleted too? ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your question was deleted with no answers, you can just repost it yourself. There's no need to involve moderators or any other members of the community in an action you can take yourself.

Looking at your question though, it was closed as "too broad" because you asked four questions in one. Individually they could fall under "tools commonly used by software developers," so they'd be on-topic on Stack Overflow. I'm not an iOS developer or an Apple user, so I can't say for certain where these questions belong. I don't see any questions about TestFlight on Ask Different, so they might be off-topic there. You might need to split them up and see which community accepts questions similar to those you're asking.