# How can I migrate a deleted question?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, migration, post-ban

I have a deleted question that was asking for a tool, which is off-topic for SO but on-topic for SR. I want to migrate it and then edit it to match SR's rules.

Unfortunately, 60 days have passed and I can no longer see the question. The other problem is that I'm question banned; this is a chance to maybe remove the ban (although I have other unsolvable questions).

How do I migrate it ?

I found [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286934/correct-workflow-for-migrating-a-deleted-question) but, as the answer says, the poster's question wasn't deleted as off-topic but as too broad. The answer doesn't tell me how to migrate my question anyway.

### PS

I'm only question-banned on SO.

Comment: `the problem is, I'm question banned , this is a chance to maybe remove the ban` You wouldn't be able to have the question migrated even if it weren't deleted. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th): `Migrations are not possible if your account is banned from asking questions on the destination site. The question will simply be closed as off topic, but not migrated.`

Comment: You're question banned on SO, or SR (or both)? You can't use migration as a way to get around the ban - **fix your previous questions**.

Comment: @jonrsharpe migration to another site will remove a deleted question from my list on SO, won't it ? if not then maybe a feature request is comming

Comment: @niceman No, it will not.  "Migrating" a question simply deletes it where it is and re-creates it on the target site (but ensures the question and each answer is attributed to the correct author).

Comment: @Servy deleting it where it is means removing it from SO which means removing a deleted question from SO, or do you mean that it's removed from SO but not from my list ?

Comment: @niceman Deleted questions are still taken into consideration in the post ban algorithm.  Deleting them does nothing to remove them from consideration.

Comment: @Servy you're just telling me "you're post banned and you don't have a chance", what to do to three deleted questions which I can't even see then

Comment: @niceman not ask off-topic questions in the first place? Not leave it more than 60 days without fixing them?

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for the advice but it is for future which I can't apply now.

Comment: @jonrsharpe sorry for letting those ones for 60 days but I'm a university student and had homeworks and exams these 60 days, my college is good at compressing the student to an extent he/she can't even itch his/her ear

Answer (score 11):

It can't be migrated.

You can re-ask the question if you refactor it into one that is appropriate for the target site.