# Merge tags “windows-store-apps” and “windows-store”

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

- [windows-store-apps](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/windows-store-apps/info) used for *5,429* questions
- [windows-store](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/windows-store/info) used for *438* questions

Since these two used for the same thing most of the time it will be easy to use only one of them  (*windows-store-apps*, to be precise) for relevant questions instead of including both.

Comment: It currently can't be a synonym since its a reverse synonym of [tag:microsoft-appstore]. We may need to consider how to deal with that.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, so do you recommend to use "microsoft-appstore" tag for all future questions instead of these two?

Comment: I'd take [tag:windows-store-apps] over *either* of them Unfortunately, its not letting me suggest *that* as a synonym either. We may need a mod to step in here, as I don't even have 5 score in the tiny [windows-store] tag to DV it to remove the current proposal.

Comment: They are just not the same thing.  [windows-store] is the house, [windows-store-apps] are the people that live inside the house.

Comment: @HansPassant But is a tag about the house really on-topic here? What question would be about the house, and not developing the apps that live in the house? There are no non-[tag:windows-store-apps] available in the [tag:windows-store]

Comment: Agree with @BradleyDotNET - I can't imagine questions about _store_only_ in the (apps) development Q/A forum.

Comment: That's rather secondary, isn't it?  We wouldn't want people that ask off-topic questions about things like store payments to tag the question with [windows-store-apps]

Comment: Right now people use tons of different tags to describe the same things and that makes difficulties for everyone involved.

Comment: I'm just thinking that that "off-topic" level in questions tagged by any of these two compared to the whole numbers of questions related to Windows Store development is so small that I would rather prefer to see all questions related to subject (and so my questions were visible to as much people with relevant experience as possible), then differentiate them so precisely.

Comment: No matter how we merge/synonymize: First step has to be to cleanup the [tag:windows-store]. I see a large number of questions there which are about app store policies, app store procedures, ... See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic)