# Should we nuke [appstore-approval] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I see that [appstore-approval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/appstore-approval) tag questions are nothing about programming. Tag itself says:

> App store approval is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Questions marked with this tag concern the approval process of an iOS or OS X application by Apple before the application is added to the App Store. If this applies to your question, it is very likely off-topic.

Should we burninate it?

Comment: Is that tag attracting a lot of bad questions? Are all questions indeed off-topic? What would be the result if we do nothing?

Comment: @rene if you see last couple of questions then all are off-topic.

Comment: there are over 1100 questions, you're setting up the community up for a lot of work. Is it really needed because I'm not convinced they look that bad.

Comment: @rene Looking at this tag, it does look to me like it's actively drawing [customer support for (your favorite company)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company) questions. IMHO this isn't even on-topic here, so it should go.

Answer (score 11):

Related: [Why we're not customer support for [your favorite company]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)

Short answer: yes, this tag should be burninated because app store policy questions aren't even on topic here. Looking at the questions, most of these questions appear to be of the "why was my app rejected" / "when will Apple approve my app" type.

Comment: Can this be done by using the nuclear option or do those 1151 questions need to be cleaned-up first?

Comment: @rene I imagine that we'd have to clean it up first, given how many of these questions are off-topic.

Comment: Also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score -8):

IMHO some of the questions with this tag are legit, and this tag makes sense for some of them. On the other hand, the tag description that explains why App Store approval *per se* is off-topic for Stack Overflow, would be enough in my eyes to keep the tag live.

Here is an example of a question that is legitimate in my eyes: [iOS app gets rejected from AppStore due to different Apple Watch icon - Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44944606/ios-app-gets-rejected-from-appstore-due-to-different-apple-watch-icon-xamarin)

The user has a technical question how to correctly set icons in his app, and the reason he needs help is not to be rejected on App Store.

Comment: Can you point to some questions using this tag that you think are on-topic, that use the tag correctly? Because we decided a long time ago that [app store approval is _not_ something it makes sense for SO to deal with](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/175701). (And see [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745)) So it's hard to see why we should have a tag for a subject that's out of scope.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I am not advocation SO support for app store approval in general. But today if somebody looks for info on this, they can see (in tag description) that this is out of scope. If you have a better way to warn these people, explain how you do it. The worst case is that you destroy and lock [tag:appstore-approval] and tomorrow we see [tag:app_store_approval] and  [tag:appstore-approve]

Comment: Fine, the honeypot argument. That doesn't square with your first sentence, though. Do you have examples of "question with this tag [that] are legit, and [for which] this tag makes sense"?

Comment: @JoshCaswell I added an example in the body. "Honeypot" is a good explanation

Comment: Well, I disagree that the App Store is relevant there, and so I continue to believe that if the App Store is the subject of the question, the question is off topic.

Comment: @JoshCaswell in my book, it's OK to disagree as long as this does not resolve in violence. Anyways, I did not see relevant questions that have App Store **subject**, and here I tend to agree with you. But in my experience, tags are not only used to mark the **subject** of a question, but also the context of a question. Otherwise, how can any question have 5 tags?

Comment: The honeypot solution isn't a solution. Either, there's a on topic question which can use that as only tag, or the tag itself shouldn't exist.