# Do accepted answers to meta questions represent official guidelines for the site?

Tags: support, meta, accepted-answer

I've recently been gripped with an intriguing question. Are users expected to know and understand the accepted answers to various question regarding potential behavior when asking and answering questions?

If an answer on Meta is accepted, is it an official guideline to be cited as a reason for closing or not answering a particular question?

If so, shouldn't the answers be accepted not by the questioner, but by the community at large and subsequently moved to the site's [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help page?

Comment: To clarify this question, it's based on a misunderstanding of a link I provided to a Meta post which discussed whether a subject was appropriate here, and Allen took my supplying that link to mean I was saying *official guidelines are contained in that Meta post*. That is not what was said (or implied) in the comment, which you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45766221/app-transport-security-rejection/45766295?noredirect=1#comment78490983_45766221), where I linked to [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Comment: Also to clarify, I did **not** downvote this question. I just added a comment to provide background.

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, there is no reliable meaning that can ever be drawn from an accept mark. An accept mark is very simply an extra vote for the OP that isnt anonymous. Sure there are side effects associated with that vote, but it is still essentially just a vote.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> If an answer on Meta is accepted, is it an ***official guideline*** to be sited as a reason for closing or not answering a particular question?

## No.

As usual (like at the main site), that only reflects (if at all) the OP's opinion this answer solved their problem/question at best.

Weight on voting of the whole community that's of least significance (regarding usefulness for future research).

---

> If so, shouldn't the answers be accepted not by the questioner, but by the community at large and subsequently moved to the site's How to ask help page?

## Again No.

Accepting an answer is the OP's privilege. It might be a sign for usefulness but is no way an ***official guideline***.

---

<sub>As it stands I'd recommend you should accept [Alexei's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/355326/8242698) to experience that yourself.</sub>

Comment: I had a difficult time searching for a similar question. Do you know if this has been asked before? To me, this relationship between meta and the proper site has been a bit baffling from the beginning.

Comment: @Allen Yes, that has been asked before and is already handled in the help pages: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 9):

No, acceptance checkmark on meta represent the same "most useful to OP" state.

You can use vote count as guidance how close post to consensus on particular issue.

Note that original authors sometime accept posts that align with what they like and don't pay much attention to votes.

Comment: _"... and don't pay much attention to votes."_ I've seen patterns like _Devil shits on the biggest heap_ towards commiseration with that other low rep user (not to mention the +2 rep for accepting an answer [at the main site of course]).