# Is there a welcome bot / be nice bot?

Tags: discussion, new-users, code-of-conduct

Recently I have noticed that completely rubbish posts get upvoted quite quickly after an initial downvote.

As this happened to me this morning again for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55686823/karma-test-cases-are-failing-randomly) I honestly start to question if there is a community bot at hand trying to be more welcoming.

Another sample of such posts that doesn't really deserve upvotes would be for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55370179/i-am-unable-to-find-code-of-changing-slider-time) (that got a +4 / -2)

Comment: No, it's just pity upvotes. Remember: it only takes 15 rep for upvotes to happen.

Comment: Somewhere out there there's a person wondering if there's a bot downvoting every post out there, and feeling obligated to upvote every post they see to counteract it.

Comment: @Servy I get that, but shouldn't posts stand on there own, or am I to black/white for seeing it that way?

Comment: The second one is a borderline spam post. I guess it's mostly there to promote the website.

Comment: @Icepickle - There's a subjective element to every vote cast on SO. Well, so long as its people casting votes, anyway. Not saying your view is invalid, but the system empowers users with other views as well. Vote according to your conscience and don't fret.

Comment: @Icepickle Lots of people don't even know that there are quality standards for questions, many more don't know what many of them are, others don't care, others disagree with them on principle, etc.

Comment: Nope, posts should *definitely* stand on their own.  Unfortunately, many people don't know, or disagree with, the goal of SO, and will vote based on criteria they really shouldn't.  It's a misuse of the system, for sure, but you can't really prevent it.

Comment: @BDL interestingly, when I flagged that one to look why it got 4 upvotes (and maybe just some kind of network around the questioner, it got declined)

Comment: Either way, neither of those questions meet our standards.  Downvote, vote to close, and move on.

Comment: Assumption: New users in the hunt of the badges `Suffrage`, `Vox Popoli` &  `Civic Duty` tend to vote without taking certain quality-aspects into consideration..

Comment: @fbueckert I would like to yeah, I am sometimes amazed which kind of posts get upvoted, and then start to question, I though I would ask about it this time :) Interesting question would be if I should create a welcome bot and randomly update new users posts / answers ^_^

Comment: @iLuvLogix so you are logically saying we should remove the badges? I also hunted some hats in that way, and loved the badge you get for deleting your own answer at -3 ^_^

Comment: Trying to get everyone to vote consistently is orders of magnitude more difficult than herding cats into a bag.  At some point, you just do what you can, and keep going.

Comment: @Icepickle 'Logically' I can't see how you can interprete an assumption why new users vote without too much concern to quality as a request to remove those badges ;)  In short: I'm not suggesting the removal of those badges ;)

Comment: @NicolBolas I realize that voting is (and should be) anonymous, but it's almost too bad that people who do "pity upvotes" aren't suspended for voting fraud. I think it's really bad for the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because some users always upvote questions in the first posts queue, **regardless of the quality of the question**.
The post may entered the queue, which means the posts are placed in the first posts queue.

Comment: So, you are proposing that because of the increased amount of intrest some people upvote it. But the 2 examples I gave were absolutely below quality, does this queue also have a "sanity" check? Should users in the new users queue have more reputation to vote correctly?

Comment: @Icepickle if burnination has shown one thing, it's that bad stuff slips past moderation some times. Questions with hundreds of upvotes are some times closed as off-topic because it was considered on-topic (or simply slipped past initial moderation). The upvotes are likely a side-effect of the welcoming wagon and don't necessarily reflect the quality of the post. Basically low-rep users who have been downvoted who see a downvote and think "this is unfair" and upvote. But the purpose behind the upvotes is just speculation from my side. Having some data to back that up would be nice though

Comment: How often question quality comes into play is something only users with access to info containing who cast the votes will be able to say for certain, but it wouldn't really surprise me. There appears to be a lot of unjustified votes both up and down (serial and revenge, + pity-votes or votes that generally ignore [ask], [answer], and gudelines posted on meta

Comment: Guidelines posted on meta? Who is even checking those @Zoe ^_^, I like to check the how-to-asks from time to time, and I try to validate my expectations concerning different subsites, but where would one find those guidelines? :)

Comment: @Icepickle eh, they're spread all over the place. There's several under the [FAQ tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq), but I'm assuming some of the newer ones end up untagged and on a "you need to dig it up"-basis. There's a partial list in [the FAQ index](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251225/6296561) too. Some of the examples include the customer support one linked in the FAQ index, along with [one covering app stores](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/6296561). There are more though, but these just serve as examples.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the "new users queue." Perhaps you mean the [First Posts queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/)? But it has no such "<50 rep" requirement...can you clarify what you're talking about in that second sentence?

Comment: @scohe001 Oops, that was the first posts queue.

Comment: @smileycreations15 but the First Posts queue doesn't look at rep, so the answer still doesn't make sense.

Comment: @scohe001 Done fixing.

Comment: @scohe001 The first post queue *does* look at rep though.  I forget how much, but if you have more than just a bit it won't show your posts in that queue.