# Where would be a good place to ask questions about Play Store policy?

Tags: discussion

Play Store gave my app status of App Content Approved with Issues

> Issue: Invalid Data safety section
> Policy Declaration for Play Safety Label: Template id: "subtype_psl_device_or_other_identifiers" > not found

Where can I find help figuring out what is "subtype_psl_device_or_other_identifiers"?

Comment: Also related (and possibly a second dupe): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/6296561

Comment: Kind of special that a search for "android subtype_psl_device_or_other_identifiers" returns literally zero results. That makes me think it is an ID which is somehow specific to your app?

Answer (score 6):

Maybe shoot support@google.com an email?  We don't control the App Store and we don't control or contextualize the exact reason why an app is or isn't approved, or why it was only partially approved.

Comment: Those guys are not very responsive. I usually end up finding the answers online. I figured StackExchange will have a site for it

Comment: Not much we can do about them not being very good at responding. This is firmly in their domain and the best you could *hope* for from for us to make vague inferences, when you actually *need* a concrete answer.

Comment: @IlyaGazman - They are likely not responsive since it's well documented [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10787469?hl=en#zippy=%2Cdata-collection)

Comment: Re *"...shoot support@google.com an email"*: You are joking, right?

Comment: @PeterMortensen The advice makes sense, we don't answer those questions, they do, why not send them an email? One of the definitions of shoot: *"direct (a glance, question, or remark) at someone."* Where's the confusion?

Comment: Also relevant: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=shoot%20me%20a%20text